# MySQL left joins query tuning

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, query-optimization

When I was optimizing MySQL query with inner joins and left joins, I realized that joining tables using id from subqueries is much faster in my case.
I use MySQL 5.7.
Id columns from all table except table4 have indexes. (Unfortunately, I didn't have rights to create index on the table4)

subquery from table1 ~ 4M rows.

t2 ~ 40M rows

t4 ~ 16K rows

t5 ~ 4K rows

query example before:

```
select t1.id, t3.id
from (select id from table1
      where created_at < '2022-10-01') tr2
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
inner join table3 t3 on t3.id = t2.id
left join table4 t4 on t4.id = t1.id
left join table5 t5 on t5.id = t1.id
```

Explain plan before:
[image]

query example after:

```
select t1.id, t3.id
from (select id from table1
      where created_at < '2022-10-01') tr2
inner join table2 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
inner join table3 t3 on t3.id = t2.id
left join (select id
           from table4) t4 on t4.id = t1.id
left join table5 (select id
                 from table5) t5 on t5.id = t1.id
```

Explain plan after:
[image]

So, the second query is much faster. Can someone give me a clue, why?

Comment: Why do you even involve t4 and t5?

Comment: I posted a part of the query just for the example. Real query is anti-join so it is ended with  'where t4.id is null and t5.id is null'. But exluding this part doesn't have too much effect on performance

Comment: MySQL 5.7 is reaching end of life in 8 months. I would consider upgrading asap.

Comment: Hi - look at the EXPLAIN PLAN for both queries. Update your question with the output if you need help

Comment: Updated post  with extra information and explain plan

Comment: Carefully analyze before and after EXPLAIN for row counts.  More rows read = more time required.  Not sure why your difference in query structure for table4 and table5. But, if it works, if must be OK.

Comment: Block Nested Loop is always a performance killer.  Look for alternatives - which you found with the change to the latest query.

Comment: I thought Block Nested Loop can help with performance. I guess, I don't undestand something. Can you explain, please?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the 'derived' table `tr2` is slower than simply `JOINing` and adding a `WHERE`.  Please try that.  It should avoid the need to "materialize".

If `created_at < '2022-10-01'` is a small part of the table, then `INDEX(created_at)` is very likely to speed up the query.

Is `id` the `PRIMARY KEY` of all the tables?  If so, why not have the the various columns in a single table?  (There are valid reasons; I am checking.)  Doing so would probably make the equivalent query much faster.  Hmmm... Looking at more details, I feel that you have "simplified" the query too much.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and a matching `EXPLAIN`.  (It is OK if your obfuscate the columns names but not the datatypes and indexes.)

Comment: "I suspect that the 'derived' table tr2 is slower than simply JOINing and adding a WHERE." -  I guess it won't give perfomance improvemence, considering that WHERE significantly helps to reduce number of records before joining. Or am I wrong? Anyway this part of the query is fast as it is. I checked it.
All the information about indexes I provided in my post with EXPLAIN I've got.